# My laptop fan stopped working and started again

Tags: windows, laptop, fan

My laptop fan stopped spinning for a month and some few days. Today fan started spinning again.

Does it need to be replaced?

Comment: What OS version are you using (your choice of tags doesn't make sense)? There is no such function to turn off your fan for a "month and few days". What did you do to get it stop working? Spilled liquid, dropped or did a poor disassembly?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely **Yes**.

The moment it stopped spinning you should of stopped using the laptop until you'd figured out why and rectified the problem.

It may just be dirt / dust build up in the laptop, which can normally be pretty easily solved by opening it up and cleaning it out, or the fan motor itself maybe fried and requires replacing.

Running the laptop without a working fan will put undue stress on the cpu and other components, possibly causing it to fail earlier, or if you're lucky just causing it to underclock so that it doesn't over heat.

Of course, it may not be running because it doesn't need to, which is possible if it's very cold where you are - but this is a unlikely explanation and would only be advisable to continuing using it if you already knew this is why it'd stopped.